# Current Limiter for a Doorbell Button

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, current-limiting

I have a doorbell button that has in internal incandescent bulb, designed to operate between 12v and 24v AC.

With a 12v DC supply across it, the bulb takes about 25mA.

The bulb in in parallel with the push button, so the device consumes about 0.3W when unpressed, and is a short-circuit when pressed.

My sense circuit can handle 0-12v, so I can read the voltage across the inputs ok.

What I am struggling with is the best way to bias the doorbell so I can read it's pressed/unpressed state and give it 12vDC so it can illuminate.

Here's what I was originally thinking:

[image: first cut with pullup]

If I put a pullup in series, the pullup value has to be pretty small so the bulb will illuminate, but when the button is pressed, the pullup has to take all of the current, so it really needs to be a large value so the current isn't higher.  I'd rather not have the current through this circuit be higher when pressing the button than when unpressed.

I've thought about using a relay, but I'm hoping to do this without any 'moving parts'

Should I use a JFET as a current limiter?  What other approaches could I consider?  This isn't high-precision; I'm looking for something I could breadboard pretty easily.

Comment: What is the purpose of your sense circuit? I'm trying to get an overall picture of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If the bulb shows 25 mA when operating at 12 VDC then this is 40\*12 or 480 Ohms. Not 73. Where does the 73 come from? Is that what it is when it is first starting to heat up? The AC source of this must be a doorbell transformer that has a *very high leakage reactance* (poor regulation.)

Comment: Perhaps consider making your DC source from a doorbell transformer? That would provide inherent isolation from mains and also would benefit from its high leakage reactance when the button is pressed. Active devices as current limiters will eat some overhead voltage. That's fine if you plan for it so that there is 12 VDC left over, though. In that case, I'd recommend planning 1.5 V of overhead. Or just use an AC doorbell transformer per its original design and arrange for your MCU to observe the positive-going half cycles when the button isn't pressed?

Comment: Yes, 73ohms is the cold resistance.  The bulb heats up and R increases to 480.

Comment: Basically, I just want to hook this up to simple MCU and read the button state.  If it weren't for the bulb, my sense circuit would be fine.  I don't mind it taking 25mA while not pressed, but not sure best way to let it do that and not take more current when pressed (It doesn't illuminate while pressed)

For now I have a 10ohm, 10watt pullup, which kind of works, but feels a little inelegeant.

Comment: @JimB. Sounds like you have a DC supply you are not willing to ditch. I still think the better solution is to stay with a doorbell transformer and just pass along the positive peaks to your MCU for observation. But if you are saying that isn't an option for you and that you ***must*** use a 12 VDC low-impedance supply that you already have, then your resistor leaves 98% of the light's voltage (once hot) and performs current limiting while cold or when the button is pressed. Inelegant, yes. But... bulletproof. (And an active circuit would take away more operating voltage for the light.)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.

Comment: Is the door bell still in the circuit? If so, why don't you use it as the pull-up? If not, I would go with a simple constant current source. It does not have to be exact.

Comment: How low are you willing to go on the voltage across the bulb (when it is lit)? If you are willing to go down to say 9.5 V, then a current fold-back circuit can keep the current low when the switch is closed.

Comment: It's hard to say, but its linear so 9.5v is better than 9 but not as good as 10. :-)

I'm inclined to try something active because while it won't help with the headroom (I lose headroom with a pullup resistor too), it could limit the power being pulled when the button is pressed.  What's a current fold-back?

Comment: Current foldback is used in many linear regulators to protect them from the effects of short circuits. When the load resistance falls below a certain point, the output voltage goes down and the current goes down as well. See https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/power-supply-electronics/current-limiter-circuit.php